# Apurar classificação do artigo com base nas visualizações de todos os artigos

Tags: php, mysql, classificação, revisão-de-código

A ideia é apurar a reputação de determinado artigo com base nas visualizações de todos os artigos existentes.

Um artigo pode ter a reputação de 1 a 5 estrelas, sendo a mesma constantemente mutável com base nas visualizações registadas para todos os artigos.

O objetivo é atribuir mais estrelas ao artigo mais visualizado, sabendo que as estrelas atribuídas são calculadas em tempo real mediante a visualização registada até ao momento em todos os artigos em catálogo.

## MySQL

Para o efeito, sempre que um artigo é visualizado, é registada a visualização numa tabela:

```mysql
DESCRIBE `product__statistic_views`
```

```
┌───────────────┬───────────┬──────┬─────┬─────────────────────┬────────────────┐
│ Field         │ Type      │ Null │ Key │ Default             │ Extra          │
├───────────────┼───────────┼──────┼─────┼─────────────────────┼────────────────┤
│ id            │ int(13)   │ NO   │ PRI │ NULL                │ auto_increment │
├───────────────┼───────────┼──────┼─────┼─────────────────────┼────────────────┤
│ product_id    │ int(13)   │ NO   │ MUL │ 0                   │                │
├───────────────┼───────────┼──────┼─────┼─────────────────────┼────────────────┤
│ session_id    │ char(100) │ NO   │ MUL │ old-na              │                │
├───────────────┼───────────┼──────┼─────┼─────────────────────┼────────────────┤
│ page_views    │ int(13)   │ NO   │ 0   │                     │                │
├───────────────┼───────────┼──────┼─────┼─────────────────────┼────────────────┤
│ date_created  │ datetime  │ NO   │ MUL │ 0000-00-00 00:00:00 │                │
└───────────────┴───────────┴──────┴─────┴─────────────────────┴────────────────┘
```

**Exemplo de um registo:**

```
┌────┬────────────┬──────────────────────────────────┬────────────┬─────────────────────┐
│ id │ product_id │ session_id                       │ page_views │ date_created        │
├────┼────────────┼──────────────────────────────────┼────────────┼─────────────────────┤
│ 2  │ 37         │ 153dd95d83bc6a6691a4c3bab42215c9 │ 3          │ 2014-12-02 18:47:17 │
└────┴────────────┴──────────────────────────────────┴────────────┴─────────────────────┘
```

<sup>Isto diz-nos que o artigo #37 tem um visitante único, cujo mesmo visualizou o produto 3 vezes na mesma sessão.</sup>

## PHP

No lado do PHP, a informação é processada da seguinte forma:

```php
/**
 * Product Rating
 *
 * Prepare the necessary HTML to present the product
 * rating stats based on their views count while
 * compared to all products views.
 * 
 * @param integer $count Product views count.
 * @param integer $grandTotal Sum of all products views.
 *
 * @return string $returnHtml HTML ready to be used.
 */
public function productRating($count=0, $grandTotal=0) {

    $returnHtml = '
    <span class="fa fa-star-o"></span>
    <span class="fa fa-star-o"></span>
    <span class="fa fa-star-o"></span>
    <span class="fa fa-star-o"></span>
    <span class="fa fa-star-o"></span>';

    if (intval($count)>=1) {

        $rating = number_format( ceil( ( ($count*100) / $grandTotal ) / 20 ), 0);

        if ($rating>0) {

            $returnHtml = '';

            for ($i=0; $i<$rating; $i++) {
                $returnHtml.= '<span class="fa fa-star" data-rating="'.$rating.'"></span>';
            }

            for ($i=5; $i>$rating; $i--) {
                $returnHtml.= '<span class="fa fa-star-o" data-rating="'.$rating.'"></span>';
            }
        }
    }

    return $returnHtml;
}
```

**Exemplo de utilização:**

```php
/* Visualizações são únicas, pelo que o total de visualizações do produto é uma
 * contagem dos registos com o seu ID na tabela em cima, e o total de visualizações
 * de todos os produtos é uma contagem de todos os registos na tabela em cima referida.
 */
$ratingHtml = $this->productRating(1, 10);
```

## HTML

O resultado será algo parecido com isto:

[image: Ilustração das estrelas que denotam a classificação do produto]

---

## Pergunta

Para o que foi descrito, a função que trata de apurar a classificação de cada produto está a desempenhar o seu trabalho de forma eficiente?

<sup>Poderá todo este processo ser simplificado?</sup>

Comment: Me explica o seguinte: aquele artigo que tiver maioria de views sobre todos os demais recebe 5 estrelas? Ou é uma questão de porcentagem? os que tiverem maior porcentagem de views em relação ao total recebem 5 estrelas... não entendi a divisão por 20 ali no código

Comment: @touchmx A grosso modo, cada estrela equivale a 20%. Se o produto estiver de 80% para cima, leva 5 Estrelas. De notar que o código pode estar 100% errado, daí esta pergunta a pedir revisão do mesmo.

Answer (score 2):

Se compreendi o código corretamente, esse método deverá gerar um valor muito baixo para cada produto, já que nenhum terá 100% das visualizações que você passa em `$grandTotal`. Uma maneira alternativa de calcular seria comparar com o produto que tem mais visualizações, em vez de comparar com a soma de todas as *views*. Em SQL, isso poderia ser feito assim:

```sql
SELECT
  product_id,
  page_views,
  CEIL((page_views / (SELECT MAX(page_views) FROM product__statistic_views)) * 100) AS percentual
FROM product__statistic_views
-- WHERE product_id = ? /* para filtrar por produto se necessário */
```

<sup>http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/93913/4</sup>

Esse método ainda teria o problema de gerar valores baixos para todos os produtos novos, que geralmente tendem a ter poucas *views*. Você poderia utilizar alguma data de referência para minimizar isso. Por exemplo, para comparar um produto com os que foram cadastrados até 7 dias antes dele (considerando que `date_created` é a data de cadastro):

```sql
SELECT
  product_id,
  page_views,
  CEIL((page_views / (SELECT MAX(page_views) FROM product__statistic_views WHERE date_created BETWEEN DATE_SUB(date_created, INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND date_created)) * 100) AS percentual
FROM product__statistic_views
-- WHERE product_id = ? /* para filtrar por produto se necessário */
```

Answer (score 0):

O cálculo está perfeito, o que creio está errado é o fato de a variável $returnHtml ser iniciada com estrelas. Nesse caso, me parece que serão exibidas mais de 5 estrelas. Então creio que o correto seja o seguinte:

```
/**
 * Product Rating
 *
 * Prepare the necessary HTML to present the product
 * rating stats based on their views count while
 * compared to all products views.
 * 
 * @param integer $count Product views count.
 * @param integer $grandTotal Sum of all products views.
 *
 * @return string $returnHtml HTML ready to be used.
 */
public function productRating($count=0, $grandTotal=0) {

    $returnHtml = '';

    if (intval($count)>=1) {

        $rating = number_format( ceil( ( ($count*100) / $grandTotal ) / 20 ), 0);

            for ($i=1; $i<=5; $i++) {
                if($i <= $rating){
                   $returnHtml .= '<span class="fa fa-star" data-rating="'.$i.'"></span>';
                }else{
                   $returnHtml .= '<span class="fa fa-star-o" data-rating="'.$i.'"></span>';
                }
            }    

        }else{
           $returnHtml = '
           <span class="fa fa-star-o"></span>
           <span class="fa fa-star-o"></span>
           <span class="fa fa-star-o"></span>
           <span class="fa fa-star-o"></span>
           <span class="fa fa-star-o"></span>';

        }

    return $returnHtml;
}
```

estou assumindo que a classe fa-star-o é a estrela desativada, a cinza que você mostrou no exemplo.

Comment: Assumiste de forma correta em relação às cores! Mas, a variável `$returnHtml` tem estrelas _desativadas_ porque se o parâmetro `$count` for 0 (zero), a ideia é ter estrelas, embora vazias. De acordo com a tua sugestão, se `$count===0` vamos ficar sem estrelas no produto porque não passa do primeiro controlo `if (intval($count)>=1) {...}`.

Comment: Entendi, vou editar. a mudança é simples.

Comment: Agora está correto, faça um teste e me de um feedback.